# How to make unique combinations of the following list of tuples

Tags: python

In python, I have a list containing the following tuples:

```
[(Bob, Tom), (GreenWood, Pearson)]
```

First `tuple` contains first names and second `tuple` contains last names.
*PS: The list I gave is a sample, the actual list varies with more names*

The thing I am trying to do is generate all the possible names that can be generated i.e

```
- Bob GreenWood
- Bob Pearson
- Tom GreemWood
- Tom Pearson
```

How can I implement this in Python preferably or any other language.

I trying to first take the `Bob in tuple 1` and make combinations with `last names in tuple 2` and do something like `tuple1[1:]` to get rid of the Bob. Then repeat (possible recursion?) with only `Tom in tuple` but I can't seem to wrap my head around how the algorithm should look like.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like this

```
from itertools import product
names = [('Bob', 'Tom'), ('GreenWood', 'Pearson')]
for item in product(*names):
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
('Bob', 'GreenWood')
('Bob', 'Pearson')
('Tom', 'GreenWood')
('Tom', 'Pearson')
```

If you wanted to print the possible names as string, then you can join the result like this

```
print(" ".join(item))
```

This will produce

```
Bob GreenWood
Bob Pearson
Tom GreenWood
Tom Pearson
```

Comment: Or `print ' '.join(item)`

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks :) Included that in the answer.

Comment: Wow this is brilliant! Simple yet elegant! Just a side note. Id change `print item` to `print(item)` coz of python 3 I guess

Comment: @Krimson Yup, you are correct. `print` is a function in Python 3.x :)